# Is the character of a “request” legally defined?

Tags: legal-terms

In general English usage the notion of a request seems to connote that compliance with it is discretionary and not required. But in legal usage and correspondence it seems to perhaps assume a different character. For example, consider the idea of a subject access *request*. In fact compliance with such requests is generally compulsory.

What is the basis for the divergence of usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To request means simply to ask politely or formally - there is no implication that an answer is optional *or* required

Some requests will be backed by law or custom such that they require a response, others do not. The former is more likely to be the case in a legal setting than in a casual setting which might be why you are finding an implication that doesn’t exist.